# Brightness controls not adjusting the brightness in ubuntu 10.10 64 bit on hp dm3t notebook

Tags: ubuntu, laptop, ubuntu-10.10, brightness

I picked up an [hp dm3t laptop](http://www.shopping.hp.com/webapp/series/category/notebooks/dm3t_series/3/computer_store) with intel HD graphics and installed ubuntu 10.10 64 bit on it. It works great -- the only problem is that the brightness controls on the keyboard don't work. The brightness is always at full. When I try to adjust it down, the indicator graphic indicates that it's going down but the actual brightness doesn't change. Is there anything that I can try to make this work? I'd really appreciate any help.

Comment: must be the intel HD graphics....works for me with an HP and nvidia.  try tweaking the driver

Comment: What should I tweak and where? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

1. Run this command:

   ```
   sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
   ```
2. Change the line:

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
   ```

   into

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_osi=Linux"
   ```
3. Then run:

   ```
   sudo update-grub
   ```
4. Restart Linux.